# Can PHP static methods legally have a visibility of protected or private?

Tags: php, oop, class

I realize that it's possible to define a static class method as private and protected in PHP. This allows for an instantiated class, or public static method to access it's own private/protected static methods.

```
protected static function jumpOver  ()
```

However I'm not sure if this is legal in the sense of OOP design. I can't find any real info stating it's ok to do this. I'm worried PHP may "patch" this in future versions if this is not a valid and break my scripts.

Comment: `protected static function` is legit, it can be used as helper method for other static methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is. Static methods are usually nothing more than helper methods that have code you possibly don't want to be public.

The other common object-oriented languages I can think of have it too (C++, Java, C#). I really don't think they're ever going to remove that feature.

Besides, the guys at PHP are slow at breaking existing features, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: uhm...isn't final the keyword you want to use to protect your code?

Comment: @dierre: `final` protects from overriding/inheritance, but it doesn't protect access.

Comment: oh, ok. Sorry I thought by saying "have code you possibly don't want to be public" was referred to the possibility of override/inherit it.

Comment: Those other languages have it too for the same good reason: as @d.raev points out, it can be used to protect those methods used by other `public static` methods which you don't want to expose.

Answer (score 0):

As Linus suggests to us in his wisdom, let's look at some code.

Say, you have your "static" class (not a thing):

```php
class MyClass
{
    public static function doThing(): void
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Now, say you wanna add another method, which shares some logic with the first one:

```php
class MyClass
{
    public static function doThing(): void
    {
        // Do something
        // Then, do this particular thing
    }

    public static function doOtherThing(): void
    {
        // Do something else
        // Then, do the same particular thing
    }
}
```

Makes sense to extract that same particular thing that both `doThing()` and `doOtherThing()` to a method of its own, right?

```php
class MyClass
{
    public static function doThing(): void
    {
        // Do something
        static::doParticularThing();
    }

    public static function doOtherThing(): void
    {
        // Do something else
        static::doParticularThing();
    }

    public static function doParticularThing(): void
    {
        // Some more generic or repetitive logic
    }
}
```

Great! Now consumers of `MyClass` can also start using `doParticularThing()`. Like with any other public API, this can lead to a situation where you remove that method because no other logic of yours depends on it anymore, and break all consummers of `doParticularThing()`. They come and create issues in your tracker. Let's say you don't want that:

```php
class MyClass
{
    public static function doThing(): void
    {
        // Do something
        static::doParticularThing();
    }

    public static function doOtherThing(): void
    {
        // Do something else
        static::doParticularThing();
    }

    protected static function doParticularThing(): void
    {
        // Some more generic or repetitive logic
    }
}
```

Now you have a class that other code can use to `doThing()` and to `doOtherThing()`, but they are safe from `doParticularThing()` that you might change or remove later. This is good API design, and your consumers will thank you if you use this approach correctly.

Comment: Credit also to @d.raev, who mentioned it first in a comment. But that comment is not very visible, and I feel this point of view needs a representation that can be accepted as an answer.

Comment: Also, as a bonus in my example, consumers of `MyClass` can change the way `doParticularThing()` and no other method works, if they need to. That's partly because the protected members are indeed `protected` and not `private`, and nothing is `final`. But also, because `doParticularThing()` is invoked with `static` and not `self`: this ensures that the inherited `doThing()` and `doOtherThing()` invoke the overridden method, and not the one of `MyClass`.